# Notification window in case of any operation in C: drive

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, notifications

I have created a sample for Notification window in silverlight4.

The issue i'm facing is that i want to show notification window whenever any operation(say file copied or deleted) is performed in my windows C: drive.

Since System.IO.FileSystemWatcher class (COM+ componenet) cannot be used in silverlight, so i found a way out using an **AutomationFactory**, it works like charm for me as long as i am using message box to show notification or default notification window but not in case of my own customnotification window.. :(

The code is like this -

```
new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (dynamic SWbemLocator = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator"))
                {
                    SWbemLocator.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3;
                    SWbemLocator.Security_.AuthenticationLevel = 4;
                    dynamic IService = SWbemLocator.ConnectServer(".", @"root\cimv2");

                    string fileSystemWatcherQuery =
                        @"SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 3 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\""'";
                    dynamic monitor = IService.ExecNotificationQuery(fileSystemWatcherQuery);

                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(@"Now listening to file changes on c:\"));

                    while (true)
                    {
                        dynamic EventObject = monitor.NextEvent();
                        string eventType = EventObject.Path_.Class;
                        string path = EventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent;
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                        {
                            System.Windows.NotificationWindow notify = new System.Windows.NotificationWindow();
                            notify.Height = 74;
                            notify.Width = 329;

                            CustomNotification custom = new CustomNotification();
                            custom.Header = "FileSystemWatcher";
                            custom.Text = eventType + ":" + path;
                            custom.Width = notify.Width;
                            custom.Height = notify.Height;
                            custom.Closed += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(custom_Closed);
                            notify.Content = custom;
                            notify.Show(5000);
                        });
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(eventType + ": " + path));
                    }
                }
            }).Start();
```

**Whenever i copied the file or delete a file from my C:, a message box appears and notification window do appears but the content is entirely blank. If i use default notification window in place of my own CustomNotification it works fine.**

**What i am guessing is, it has something related to threading, not sure though.. ??**

CustomNotification is a class which derives from ContentConrol class and have two dependency properties namely "Header" & "Text". The control template for this i have declared in different xaml file like this -

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomNotification">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomNotification">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="7"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB9B9CC"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9191AB" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEDEDF5" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C3D7" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="closeButton" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1, 3" Width="16" Height="13">
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Image Source="x.png"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5, 7">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontFamily="Verdana" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="11"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Here goes my CustomNotification class code -

```
 public class CustomNotification : ContentControl
    {
        public CustomNotification()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomNotification);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Header",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(CustomNotification),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnHeaderPropertyChanged));

        /// <summary>
        ///   Gets or sets a value that indicates whether 
        ///   the <see cref="P:System.Windows.Controls.Label.Target" /> field is required. 
        /// </summary>
        public string Header
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(CustomNotification.HeaderProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(CustomNotification.HeaderProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private static void OnHeaderPropertyChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(CustomNotification),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnTextPropertyChanged));

        /// <summary>
        ///   Gets or sets a value that indicates whether 
        ///   the <see cref="P:System.Windows.Controls.Label.Target" /> field is required. 
        /// </summary>
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(CustomNotification.TextProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(CustomNotification.TextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            Button closeButton = GetTemplateChild("closeButton") as Button;
            if (closeButton != null)
            {
                closeButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(closeButton_Click);
            }
        }


        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Closed;

        void closeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = this.Closed;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Based on your description I would look into your CustomNotification implementation

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if u need something else? Nd thnx for any help.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your CustomNotification class is just a user control (i.e. inherits directly from UserControl)?  Assuming so, this line:

```
notify.Content = tb;
```

is wrong.  I don't know what tb is, but it should be:

```
notify.Content = custom;
```

Then you'll see the content.

Note that you have to be careful to not try and show a notification whilst another one is currently being displayed.  You'll get an exception, so you'll need to keep track of this.

Hope this helps...

Chris Anderson

Comment: Sorry Chris. It was like that only. I mistakenly copied wrong data. Actually tb was textblock instance which i was trying to set as the content which works perfectly fine but my custom thing not working. Nd yeah CustomNotification is  a class which derives from ContentControl. I have updated my question accordingly..

Comment: I just gave it a go (without using your custom control), and it worked fine (I tested it using this line for its content instead: notify.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = eventType + ":" + path };). Try that instead of your custom control, just to see if it works (and narrows down the problem). For this scenario, I think a user control rather than a custom control is probably more appropriate, though it shouldn't stop it from working. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Yeah, i have already mentioned that in my question that it works fine in case we use simple textblock but not in case of my custom control. what i think is it is not able to fetch the style from xaml, not sure though. Any inputs??

Comment: Sorry, missed that in your comment.  OK, as you say, my guess then is that the custom control's template isn't being applied to it.  Did you set its DefaultStyleKey in the class's constructor? What's the code for that class? Do you have the style in the right place (in Themes\Generic.xaml)?

Comment: Yeah i have done that. Even on a normal button click, custom notification is coming as expected but not when i used this threading code. I have pasted the code for my CustomNotification class as well.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me.  Well it required one change.  You were missing the <Setter Property="Template"> line in the control's style. But you said it worked on a button click, so I'm guessing that was a different issue.

Comment: Did you implemented the exact scenario as i mentioned. I mean hv u followed the exact steps including the thread scenario?? Yeah, there was a template thing, i only posted the relevant code.. :)

Comment: Yep. Followed it as you described. No changes, except the one I mentioned.